# Enable/Disable Spring-ws at runtime

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

Is there a spring-ws bean property that allows to enable or disable the webservice based on a value from some .properties file?

My war have a web app and a webservice together, but, in some cases, i'll just need the web app running. So, it would be great to hide the wsdl and further requests on WS.

here is the bean I'm using for show the wsdl to the user.

```
<!-- Bean utilizado pelo webservice -->
<sws:annotation-driven />

<bean id="testService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="schemaCollection">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="inline" value="true" />
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
                    <value>schemas/Operations.xsd</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="testService" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="testServices" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints" />
</bean>
```

The endpoint is implemented using @Endpoint annotation

Comment: May be changing the endpoint dynamically could help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles) abstraction. Looks like it is the best for you to disable all those beans by the specific `activeProfile` condition.

Comment: Artem Bilan, I was researching about profiles, but as far as I know, this feature was inserted on Spring 3.1. Unfortunately, we are still using Spring 3.0.5. The framework update is being done on a branch and will take some time.

Comment: Well, I'd add otherwise some simple `javax.servlet.Filter` to prevent access to those resources counting some option for the application.